# Why does my fetched JSON has [object] instead of an array?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

I would like to sort out some data from a Fetch API JSON. Using Postman GET is fine, but when I use console.log() to print out the result, it has the [Array] printed out instead. Also, I cannot access the "foodNutrients" array in my code.

When I enter the url using Postman GET

```
"foodNutrients": [
                {
                    "nutrientId": 1051,
                    "nutrientName": "Water",
                    "nutrientNumber": "255",
                    "unitName": "G",
                    "derivationCode": "A",
                    "derivationDescription": "Analytical",
                    "value": 0E-8
                },
                {
                    "nutrientId": 1003,
                    "nutrientName": "Protein",
                    "nutrientNumber": "203",
                    "unitName": "G",
                    "derivationCode": "A",
                    "derivationDescription": "Analytical",
                    "value": 24.40000000
                },
               ]
```

But when I use Fetch and use console.log()

```
  {
    //some fields

    foodNutrients: [Array]
  },
```

my code

```
const dataFilter= (response) => {
    console.log(response)

 async function getData() {
    fetch('https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/foods/search?api_key=DEMO_KEY&query=0')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => dataFilter(response))
  }
  getData()
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: its an object in postman and in console.log both i don't what are you trying to ask exactly

Comment: It's an array in both

Comment: What do you get when you do `console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2))`?

Answer (score 2):

This is just how the Console expresses "There is a large array here".

It's a performance feature which works by simplifying the view on the data.

You could, for example, change `console.log(response)` to `response.foodNutrients.forEach(nut => console.log(nut))` will show the objects in the array.

Comment: Ah. I should also be able to access the data inside it right?